# TryUpdateModel updating order

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Is there any way to control updating order during execution of `TryUpdateModel`? I need one property to be valid in order to update other property, but by default the second property is still null when the other one is being updated.

What is the default updating order? The weird thing is that the needed property in my code is declared first in both model and form. I can't find any information about this execution order in the Internet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any way to control updaing order during execution of TryUpdateModel?

No, no order can be guaranteed and you should never count on any order. That's the reason why you should be performing validation once the model is fully bound and not inside your view model setters.

You could use data annotation attributes or once you realize how limited they are (especially in terms of conditional and more complex validation scenarios), switch to [FluentValidation.NET](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/) which [integrates very nicely](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=mvc&referringTitle=Documentation) with ASP.NET MVC and which I more than strongly recommend you.

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge the binder gets the properties in order that they are typed in in the class.  Last I saw it does a GetProperties and that's how the method loads.

However, because this is a private implementation, don't count on this.  If you have this sort of constraint, create your own ModelBinder.